# Python, detect a character with on quote inside a string between double quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, character, single-quotes

I have the example bellow of a tuple:

```
('XXXX','XXXX',"XXXX's Something",'XXXX')
```

I want to turn it into:

```
('XXXX','XXXX','XXXX''s Something','XXXX')
```

The reason why i'm trying to do it, is that this input will be ingested in **Azure SQL database** which skips the quote by using another single quote (as shown above).

How can I detect only the single quotes that are inside characters between double quotes?

Best regards,

Comment: Would something as simple as casting it to a string and using a `.replace("\"", "'")` work?

Comment: There should be no problem with a single quote if you feed in the values with `parameters` in the [`execute`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#id15) function. It seems like you try to construct your SQL string manually.

Comment: The outermost quotes are not part of the value.  `'XXX'` and `"XXX"` are the same string.  You should just be able to use `if "'" in item:` to detect if a string contains a single quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a tuple comprehension with `tuple()` and a generator expression.

```
>>> t = ('XXXX','XXXX',"XXXX's Something",'XXXX')
>>> tuple(s.replace("'", "''") for s in t)
('XXXX', 'XXXX', "XXXX''s Something", 'XXXX')
```